# Dynamically change config files in .Net Application based on environments through Bamboo

Tags: c#, deployment, app-config, environment, bamboo

I have a windows service written in .net c#. We have three different environments say `dev`, `test` and `prod`. I also have 3 different config files for 3 environments say `devAppConfig` , `TestAppConfig` and `ProdAppConfig`.

Earlier, we used to deploy manual, so we used to replace the config files and deploy the binaries.Now the deployments are to be automated for that we are using Bamboo.

Now my question is how do I dynamically change the AppConfig for different environment deployments.

I have 3 different stages in Bamboo naming `DevDeploy` , `TestDeploy`, `ProdDeploy`. When I run these stages, it has to change the config file and do the deployment, but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for my issue?

[image]

Comment: @PranavSingh This is not duplicate as I want these changes to be done in Bamboo. And in the link provided by you, there is no mention of bamboo anywhere

Comment: I hope if you have multiple environments, then you will create multiple deployment projects too. So for each deployment projects, you can write a powershell script or node script to choose the config file and deploy using it.

Comment: @Chidambaram I have only build project and not deployment project. Since it is copying of binaries, I'm using powershell scripts to copy the binaries from Bamboo agent to destination server. Do you think I should take deployment project instead of build project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this would work:

1. Create few configuration files in some directory in the solution in the format Config.ConfigurationName.xml, eg Config.**DEV**.xml, Config.**Test**.xml...
2. Add PreBuild event (by the csproj properties window or manually in the csproj file), for example: `<PropertyGroup><PreBuildEvent>xcopy /y (ProjectDir)\Configs\Config.$(Configuration).xml $(ProjectDir)\CONFIG\Config.xml</PreBuildEvent></PropertyGroup>`
   or in VS rigth click on the project -> Properties:
   [image]
3. Add few configurations in VS in Configuration Manager for different configuration eg. **DEV, Test**.
   My project configuration:

[image: My project configuration]

4. Execute in the Bamboo msbuild with arguments: `/p:SolutionConfiguration=%CONFIGURATION%` where %CONFIGURATION% is a variable in Bamboo saying on which ENV you are deploying, eg **DEV, Test** etc.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I was trying this approach. I'm getting this error when I added the prebuildevent as mentioned in the second point. And also the project is not loading in VS.  Error : The element <#text> beneath element <PreBuildEvent> is unrecognized.

Comment: I have added the image in my question for the same

Comment: Sorry, I skipped the place where this PreBuildEvent node should be placed. It should be a new PropertyGroup: <PropertyGroup><PreBuildEvent>... but I think the best option is to do this by the VS. I will add a screen in a moment

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help