# Change to appropriate config file based on the environment variable without building the application multiple times

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I have a windows application developed in c# which has 3 config files namely `dev.config`, `qa.config` and `prod.config`.

In my main `app.config`, I have written something like this:

```
<appSettings configSource="dev.config" />
```

And when ever the I have deploy in different environment , I edit the `app.config` file from the binaries, change it to appropriate config file and deploy it (copy paste the binaries in the VM).

To automate this, at first , I have added a pre-build event which replaces the complete app.config file to appropriate environment file using xcopy, as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628984/8930751) answer.
The problem with this is , I had to build the code 3 times for deploying in 3 different environments.

```
MSBuild.exe "C:\test\TestProject.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=dev
MSBuild.exe "C:\test\TestProject.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=qa
MSBuild.exe "C:\test\TestProject.sln" /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=prod
```

This creates 3 binaries separately in 3 different folder `dev`, `qa`, `prod` in `bin` folder.

I have also read about `slow cheetah`, which also does something similar.I have to build the code again and again for different environment based on the `Configuration Manager`.

I don't know if this is possible, but my requirement is to only build once and deploy the same binaries in different environments.In the server wherever I'm deploying, I will have a system environment variable set like:

```
environmentType = dev or qa or prod
```

And somewhere in the code I should read the enviroment variable

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environmentType")`

and map to the appropriate config file. In short , there should not be any manual intervention for changing anything , or should not be building multiple times.

Or is there any way I can read the environment variable in `app.config` and write something like :

```
if env = "dev"
 <appSettings configSource="dev.config" />
else if env ="qa"
 <appSettings configSource="qa.config" />
else 
 <appSettings configSource="prod.config" />
```

Any guidance or help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: A common way to handle this is to create all the config files during the build and rename the file for the required environment during deployment.

Comment: You could pass the config file(s) as arguments (or default to prod, but swap it out if one is specified as an argument)

Comment: @John where should I pass the argument?

Comment: [Question on how to pass command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application)

Comment: @John ok I understood what you meant by arguments. Say I have passed the argument. Where and how will I write code to swap the config file? Can you please explain in detail.

Comment: There are some [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150644/change-default-app-config-at-runtime) for it, which is why I suggest defaulting to prod and only swapping for the other environments.

Comment: I'm not sure what application you are developing but I see your question is tagged as windows-services which makes me believe there is no UI. If that's the case I would seriously look at having your code ported to a C# .net core project. In C# .net core you can run everything using ASPNCETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=qa/dev/prod and it will run with different json files named appsettings.[qa/dev/prod].json
I converted to .net core a year ago and the transition is not big and almost everything is for the better. https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/